Why is a surrounding a-tag smaller then a span inside?
I have an <a> tag surrounding a <span> tag like in this example:


a {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 100%;
}
<a href="/">
  <span>Hello World!</span>
</a>



Although both have the same font-size and line-height, when inspecting both tags, the a-tag is only 18px high, while the span got a height of 20px.
I'm not getting why the <span> inside is higher than the surrounding <a>? What's the reason?

Inline elements nearly always have a little extra space at the bottom irrespective of line-height.

Well line-height:100% means to set the line-height equal to font-size (18px in your case). Since the height is auto the height will be set equal to line-height. As @Paulie_D mentioned, it is not enough. In most cases you want to use unitless line-heights.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image Set the span to display:block and the extra space goes away.

@Paulie_D  display:none does that also :) ;)

The span's height is the sum of the font's ascent and descent, which often, but not always, is greater than the font's em height that is being used to determine the height of the a element.

it's font related, the height of span is called "content area". See the duplicate for more detail



a {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
<a href="/">
<span>Hello World!</span>
</a>



It's the discrepancy in how elements are displayed inline vs block. If you run the code snippet above you'll see that they match now. This is a nuanced part of CSS that isn't well documented. What you're probably seeing is the extra space that most browsers add to inline elements for descenders within content. (j, p, q, y, etc.).
Chrome, for example, uses LayoutNG as their text layout engine. If you look through that you can see some of the liberties it takes with text layout (specifically for inline elements).
